# How to upload or update the cloud service certificate with Azure REST ARM API

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services, azure-resource-manager

I have to upload a cloud service cert.

PUT or POST on this URI is not working   `subscriptions/%sub_Id%/resourceGroups/%rg_Name%/providers/Microsoft.ClassicCompute/domainNames/%cloudService_Name%/servicecertificates`

I am getting "InvalidRequestUri",

Please help me .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use something like this:

```
"path": "subscriptions/%sub_Id%/resourceGroups/%rg_Name%/providers/Microsoft.ClassicCompute/domainNames/%cloudService_Name%/servicecertificates/SHA1-%THUMBPRINT%",
"body": {
     "thumbprintAlgorithm": "SHA1",
     "thumbprint": "%THUMBPRINT%",
     "data": "%base64encodedcert%",
     "certificateFormat": "pfx",
     "password": "password" << this is in plain text I believe
}
```

Where %thumbprint% = sha1 thumbprint of your certificate, %base64encodedcert% your pfx encoded in base64.

Comment: {
"error": {
"code": "InvalidRequestContent",
"message": "The request content was invalid and could not be deserialized: 'Could not find member 'data' on object of type 'ServiceCertificate'. Path 'data', line 2, position 8.'."
}
}

Comment: Working .. Apparantly the request body parameters should be mentioned within  properties

Comment: @HariPriyaThangavel could you please elaborate more the json body template

Comment: Something like tihs ===> 
`"body": {
     "properties" : {
          "thumbprint": "%THUMBPRINT%",
          "data": "%base64encodedcert%",
          "certificateFormat": "pfx",
          "password": "password"
        }
}`